# How to enqueue stylesheets in child-theme functions.php?

Tags: css, child-theme, wp-enqueue-style

I know this topic is old hat, but I still got issues with that.
I use the elementor child-theme and try to enqueue the following stylesheets

1. hello-child-theme-folder: style.css
2. hello-child-theme/assets/css: style.css

```
function hello_elementor_child_enqueue_scripts() {
            wp_enqueue_style( 'hello-elementor-child-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css', ['hello-elementor-theme-style',],'1.0.0');
            wp_register_style( 'test', get_template_directory_uri() . '/assets/css/style.css' );
            wp_enqueue_style( 'test' ); 
        }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'hello_elementor_child_enqueue_scripts' );
```

I tried several other ways like described here: [How Can I Use A Child Theme Effectively When Parent's CSS Is Located in a 'CSS folder'?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/213555/how-can-i-use-a-child-theme-effectively-when-parents-css-is-located-in-a-css-f/213557#213557)

If I use this standard, my page gets blank:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
    function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Enqueue styles properly in a child theme and stylesheets location](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/285416/enqueue-styles-properly-in-a-child-theme-and-stylesheets-location)

Answer (score 0):

`get_template_directory_uri` always refers to the parent theme. `get_stylesheet_directory_uri` refers to the currently active theme, which in this case is the child theme.